# Why is pyauto gui and Pycharm not working for me?

Tags: python, pycharm, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True

pyautogui.click(274, 783)
```

I'm running Pycharm on a Mac. I have tried installing pyautogui from the interpreter AND with the terminal via pip3. I'm trying to run a simple test to see if it will do 1 mouse click for me, but responds with:

```
/Users/user/PycharmProjects/NewContractBuyingMacro/venv/bin/python "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/NewContractBuyingMacro/Buying FD Macro 1.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/NewContractBuyingMacro/Buying FD Macro 1.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/NewContractBuyingMacro/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 241, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/NewContractBuyingMacro/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 100, in <module>
    from rubicon.objc import ObjCClass, CGPoint
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/NewContractBuyingMacro/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rubicon/objc/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .runtime import (  # noqa: F401
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/NewContractBuyingMacro/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rubicon/objc/runtime.py", line 785
    self.restype, *self.argtypes = ctypes_for_method_encoding(self.encoding)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I thought it might have something to do with Mac not wanting a program to control the mouse, but now I don't think so. I imagine it's something simple. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should add code here too it says invalid syntax so might be syntax problem

Comment: Are you running on Python 3?, This code works in a Linux system

Comment: i find your setup weird because the log seems to say that your venv is python 2,7 but you tried installing it using pip 3(which is for python 3).
if you don't need to use python 2.7 try changing your venv to python 3.x.(i tried PyAutoGui on 3.8 and it works fine in my mac).

I tried installing it using python 2.7 and got the same error(only in my mac but not on my windows laptop), it may be due to the macos version you use, but i don't think it will be fixed since support for python 2.x have been deprecated January 1st this year.

Comment: Hello, this error is probably solved [in this github issue](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/426).

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason why this issue may occur is because your Python interpreter on PyCharm is an older version (2.7 or older). **Changing the interpreter to Python 3 will fix this issue**.

The Pyautogui only runs with the latest Python version and they doesn’t have any legacy versions of Python supported. To change the interpreter, navigate to settings > preference > python interpreter, and select the python3 interpreter (Location of interpreter - `/usr/bin/python3`).
If you are not able to change the interpreter, please refer to video tutorials